# Error: Could not find or load main class .Works on eclipse but not in command line

Tags: java

I am using Mac. I tried to run java application through command line. It is giving me error Error: Could not find or load main class.

what i did was

1. went to the directory where my main class is
2. javac myfile.java (it worked also).
3. java myfile.

> Error: Could not find or load main class

So far i remember, it worked previously even in command line. Note that it still works on eclipse previously and now.

Comment: you should use java classname.what is  classname of myfile.java?probably it is not a public class

Comment: This error happens when your class name is not the same as java file name. If a class is public, then it must be put in a java file of the same name. Go to the folder of your java file and see the class file generated when you compile the java file.

Comment: The class file generated is of the same name as of my java file. My main class is public and the name is also the same as my filename. But when viewing my class file it shows that "There is no source file attached to the class file World.class " Any suggestion